# Accessing custom settings in Reports

Tags: apex, reporting, customsetting

I have a custom setting field which gets updates with the health of the process. I want to display this field in Reports to show whether the process is up and running. Is there a way I can expose this value in Reports? I do not see a way to enable reporting on custom settings.

Will I have to use a normal custom object and 'enable reports' to access this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use normal custom Object and **Enable Reports** to access this value. Because at present **Salesforce** doesn't support this feature. However an  [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hsCSAAY) has been raised already.

You can vote for this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hsCSAAY).

Hope I answered your question.